# Can curlies be omitted for try and/or catch blocks, as for if and else ones?

Tags: javascript, syntax, if-statement, try-catch, curly-braces

```
if (foo) {
  bar;
}
```

can be shortened to

```
if(foo) bar;
```

since it's only one statement in the block.

I'm wondering if the same applies to try/catch... I don't like extra cruft in my code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to ECMAScript 5, a block is required, which means you need the curly braces.

https://es5.github.io/#x12.14

> TryStatement :
>
> `try Block Catch`
>
> `try Block Finally`
>
> `try Block Catch Finally`
>
> Catch :
>
> `catch ( Identifier ) Block`
>
> Finally :
>
> `finally Block`

https://es5.github.io/#x12.1

> Block :
>
> `{ StatementList opt }`
>
> StatementList :
>
> `Statement`
>
> `StatementList Statement`

Comment: @user1689607: You're quoting, why not cite what you quote? Specifically, [`try`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.14) and [block](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.1).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Isn't *"According to ECMAScript 5"* and links to an HTML version of the spec sufficient?

Comment: @user1689607: Ah, sorry, I phased out after "github." There is now a **canonical** HTML version (linked above). *(In any case, lest you get the wrong impresssion, +1)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That's alright... I'm a little torn between linking to the official spec and the github version with its hyperlinks and such.

Comment: @user1689607: Yeah, that github version is nice. The official version has reasonable linking, but it's not at the same level.